# Custom Sign Up Form for a Custom WordPress Website

Tags: signup

I am building a music eCommerce website, which sells some audios.
I have built a sign up form with 5 text boxes of Name, Email, Password, Username, Phone number. I am saving this data in a wp-registration table.

How can I link this sign up form with the website in such a way that if a user registers, then only he is able to see all the music content, otherwise just the normal text.

Here is the sign up code.

```
      <?php
      /* Template Name: Sign Up */
      get_header();
      $fNameErr  = $familyNameErr = $phoneErr = $emailErr = $passwordErr = "";
      $error_css = $fName = $familyName = $phone = $email = $password =  "";

      if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
      if (empty($_POST["fName"])) {
      $fNameErr = 'background-color:#ff4338';

      } else {
      $fName = test_input($_POST["fName"]);
      // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
      if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $fName)) {
        $fNameErr = "*";
      }
     } 



     if (empty($_POST["familyName"])) {
     $error_css = 'background-color:#ff4338';
   } else {
     $familyName = test_input($_POST["familyName"]);
     // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
     if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $familyName)) {
        $familyNameErr = "*";
      }
    }


    if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $error_css = 'background-color:#ff4338';
    } else {
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
    }
}



if (empty($_POST["phone"])) {
    $error_css = 'background-color:#ff4338';
} else {
    $phone = test_input($_POST["phone"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
    if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/", $phone)) {
        $phoneErr = "*";
    }
}



if (empty($_POST["password"])) {
    $error_css = 'background-color:#ff4338';
} else {
    $password = test_input($_POST["password"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
}



global $wpdb;


$wpdb->insert('wp_registration', array(
    'First_Name' => $_POST['fName'],
    'Last_Name' => $_POST['familyName'],
    'Phone' => $_POST['phone'],
    'Email' => $_POST['email'],
    'Password' => $_POST['password']
), array(
    '%s',
    '%s'
));

}
?>


<form action="index.php" class="modal-content animate" method="post">
    <div class="container">
        <input id="fName" name="fName" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Prénom nom'" onfocus="this.placeholder=''" placeholder="Prénom nom" required="" style="<?php echo $fNameErr; ?>" type="text"> 
        <input name="familyName" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Nom de famille'" onfocus="this.placeholder=''" placeholder="Nom de famille" required="" style="<?php echo $error_css; ?>" type="text"> 
        <input name="phone" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Numéro de téléphone'" onfocus="this.placeholder=''" placeholder="Numéro de téléphone" required="" style="<?php echo $error_css; ?>" type="number"> 
        <input name="email" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Courriel'" onfocus="this.placeholder=''" placeholder="Courriel" required="" style="<?php echo $error_css; ?>" type="text">
        <input name="password" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Mot de passe'" onfocus="this.placeholder=''" placeholder="Mot de passe" required="" style="<?php echo $error_css; ?>" type="password"><br>

        <div class="buttons">
            <input class="btn btn-primary custom-button red-btn" name="submit" type="submit" value="Inscription">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: how are you dealing with the audio files - are they already restricted from downloads somehow?

Comment: Right now, they are on the downloads page and everybody can download them. I want to restrict this only for the login users. But I don't seem to link the sign up form with the sign form and the wordpress website.

Comment: well, it might be a bit more complicate than that to code. Check some plugins like Restrict Content Pro. Or check Easy Digital Downloads

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this plugins can help you 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/pagerestrict/ 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-access-control/

**Update**

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    // you content
}
else {
    // you text
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

When the user is authorized, him ID was write in global array. This ID you can take from this array.

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
```

I don't know structure your table, but you need to have user ID field like in `wp_users` table. Make a request to the database.

```
global $wpdb

$value = $wpdb->get_result("SELECT `user_name_in_your_table`
                            FROM `wp_registration`
                            WHERE `user_id` = '$current_user->ID'");

if($value[0]->user_name_in_your_table !== ''){
    //access
} else{
    //denied
}
```

Comment: Would these plugins work for the custom sign up and custom sign in forms ? And I don't want to hide the full page. I Just want to hide the audio files.

Comment: @Jon_Snow view my update answer

Comment: but that if ( is_user_logged_in() ), won't that just check if a wordpress user is logged in or not. if ( is_user_logged_in() ) is using the wp-users table I guess and I am storing the data in a custom table wp-registration

Comment: @Jon_Snow It's your custom table?

Comment: Yes it is. I just don't know how to integrate that with the the content of the website

Comment: @Jon_Snow get user id from an array that return `wp_get_current_user()` function. After this take in your custom table info about this user.

Comment: Could you explain this one further ? My table name is wp_registration

Comment: @Jon_Snow view my update answer

Comment: Lovely. Will try that but how will I deny the user from seeing the download section in the else statement

Comment: @Jon_Snow For example redirect